# How to create a new list from values from a existing list

Tags: python, list

How do I create a new list with every score that is above the class average? extend doesn't work, but how do I add all the values that is above the average to the new list?

```
grades = [88, 95, 77, 75, 84, 65, 50, 100, 87, 84, 95, 96, 92, 81, 75]
sum1 = 0     
for x in grades: 
  sum1 += x  

numGrades = len(grades)

average = (sum1/numGrades)
print("The average for the class was: ",average)

aboveAve = []
num1 = 0
for x in grades: 
  if x >= average:
    aboveAve.extend(0)
print(aboveAve)
```

Comment: Not `extend`, but *`append`*!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use

```
aboveAve.append(x)
```

instead of

```
aboveAve.extend(0)
```

For a shorter solution, you could use a *list comprehension* for this.

```
grades = [88, 95, 77, 75, 84, 65, 50, 100, 87, 84, 95, 96, 92, 81, 75]
average = sum(grades ) / len(grades)
aboveAve = [item for item in grades if item >= average]
```

Comment: but how would I add the values higher than the average to the new list aboveAve?

Comment: Just use a list comprehension like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this instead of extend:

```
 aboveAve.append(x) 

print(aboveAve) #in line with for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace `aboveAve.extend(0)` with `aboveAve.extend([x])`